# SQL Developer tool doesn't have "Application Express" node in the file hiearchy in the Connections Tab

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I  want to work with the SQL Developer. And for now, I have two SQL Developer versions, one at my office (4.2) and the other one is at home (4.1) 
On both versions, I don't have section Application Express > Import Application sections in the Connections tab.

I've found this article on the Internet

https://iadviseblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/exportimport-apex-applications-in-sql-developer/

But, I cannot see this option.

[image]

You know why or is there a way to see this?

Comment: Do you have any idea @thatjeffsmith ?

Comment: "Open the connection to the schema where you’re application is located and search for the “Application Express” directory:". Do you have that - a schema where you're application is located ?

Comment: I want to import my apex application into the SQL Developer. @VBokšić

Comment: @general46 see Kris' answer, it's his code :) also 4.1 and 4.2 are both old

Comment: I've also installed Oracle Database 19c version and SQL Developer v.19.2. I cannot see this in this version too @thatjeffsmith

Comment: Right, you need to install apex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine to show this node in the trees, sql developer does a query from `apex_release` as the connected user. Then to show the list of applications the tool issues this sql where :SCHEMA is the connected user.

```
select * from (select   WORKSPACE,   workspace_id,
    APPLICATION_ID,
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    APPLICATION_NAME||' ('||APPLICATION_ID||')'  short_name,
    owner,
    pages,
    LAST_UPDATED_ON last_updated,
    VERSION,
    AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME,
    theme_number
    from apex_applications)
    where owner = :SCHEMA
```

TL;DR It's either permissions or the version of apex is too old.  In the worksheet try these 2 selects.

Comment: Hi @Kris Rice, when I execute this statement, I get "table or view does not exist" error.

Comment: Right so that’s why it’s not in the tree.  Double check apex is installed and greater than 5.1